# GMail Manager Add-on issue

Tags: macos, firefox, gmail, browser-addons

Over the last couple weeks the add-on has stopped signing in automatically and showing me if I have new messages. Does anyone have a simple fix for this and why it is happening? I figured there would be an update for this by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a known issue since Google made some changes to the login process. Update it to [0.5.7.5](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1320). It's been fixed.

Have fun.

Comment: Thanks... odd that firefox didn't notify me of the update that was available